# Content type Images not displaying

Tags: views, entities, nodes, media

I have created views to display images. Clicking on the image takes to content. View displays the image but when clicking on image it takes to content where image is not displaying. Please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the manage display of the content type?

Comment: Yes i  have checked. Actually image breaks.

Comment: Open the image link in a new tab. If it shows forbidden, then you should give permission to the files folder.

Comment: Did you adjust your content type template to show your image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a permissions issue. You need to ensure the web user (apache?) has access to these files. I typically just

```
chmod -R www-data:www-data sites/default/files
```

and it does the job.